# Como validar PIS(Programa de Integração Social) em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando de uma função que valide *PIS*. Já procurei e os que encontro, não funcionam.

Encontrei esse:

```
function validarPIS(pis) {
    var multiplicadorBase = "3298765432";
    var total = 0;
    var resto = 0;
    var multiplicando = 0;
    var multiplicador = 0;
    var digito = 99;

    // Retira a mascara
    var numeroPIS = pis.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');

    if (numeroPIS.length !== 11 ||
        numeroPIS === "00000000000" ||
        numeroPIS === "11111111111" ||
        numeroPIS === "22222222222" ||
        numeroPIS === "33333333333" ||
        numeroPIS === "44444444444" ||
        numeroPIS === "55555555555" ||
        numeroPIS === "66666666666" ||
        numeroPIS === "77777777777" ||
        numeroPIS === "88888888888" ||
        numeroPIS === "99999999999") {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            multiplicando = parseInt(numeroPIS.substring(i, i + 1));
            multiplicador = parseInt(multiplicadorBase.substring(i, i + 1));
            total += multiplicando * multiplicador;
        }

        resto = 11 - total % 11;
        resto = resto === 10 || resto === 11 ? 0 : resto;

        digito = parseInt("" + numeroPIS.charAt(10));
        return resto === digito;
    }
}
```

Mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: Link para a especificação oficial: http://www.macoratti.net/alg_pis.htm
Se você não encontrar algo pronto, dá para implementar em cima disso.

Comment: Karina, o algoritmo do site que o @Haroldo_OK forneceu faz exatamente o que o seu código faz. Além disso, eu testei o seu código e ele me parece estar correto (embora dê para simplificar um pouco). Assim sendo, você poderia explicar porque não conseguiu fazer ele funcionar? Que problema exatamente ocorreu?

Answer (score -2):

Oi, segue o codigo corrigido, só rodar em JAVA.

```
public class ValidaPIS {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = ValidaPIS("12121212124");
    if(i==0)
        System.out.println("PIS OK");
    else
        System.out.println("PIS INVALIDO");
}

public static Integer ValidaPIS(String numeroPIS) {

    String multiplicadorBase = "3298765432";

    Integer iSoma = 0;
    Integer iResto = 0;
    Integer iDV = 99;

    Integer multiplicando = 0;
    Integer multiplicador = 0;
    Integer iDVInformado = 99;

    Integer i;
    Integer iRet = 0;

    // Retira a mascara
    numeroPIS = numeroPIS.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

    if (numeroPIS.length() != 11 || numeroPIS == "00000000000")
        iRet = iRet--;
    else {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            multiplicando = Integer.parseInt(numeroPIS.substring(i, i+1));
            multiplicador = Integer.parseInt(multiplicadorBase.substring(i, i+1));

            iSoma += multiplicando * multiplicador;
        }

        iResto = iSoma % 11;
        if(iResto > 0)
            iDV = 11 - iResto;
        else
            iDV = 0;

        iDVInformado = Integer.parseInt(numeroPIS.substring(10,11));
        if(iDV != iDVInformado)
            iRet--;
    }
    return iRet;
}
```

}

Comment: Mas a pergunta é sobre JavaScript, não Java :(

Comment: É legal o esforço em tentar ajudar, mas se não sabe fazer em JS, poderia ao menos explicar a lógica que usou para corrigir, aí talvez sirva para a autora. Se explicar os pontos que tem problema e como resolveu, deixando o Java como exemplo, TALVEZ salve a resposta (vai depender do entendimento da comunidade).

Comment: Gente, é a lógica que importa, não a linguagem